# Memcpy doesn't copy all data from listT structure

Tags: c, list, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy

I am trying to create a list (deck) of lists (deckBucket). When placing the deck inside the deckBucket the deck->size and deck->dataSize fields are not copied with memcpy inside the addToList() function.
These are the list, list node and card (not really relevant) structures.

```c
typedef struct card {
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int symbl;
} card;

typedef struct listNodeT {
    void* data;
    struct listNodeT* nextPtr;
    struct listNodeT* prevPtr;
} listNodeT;

typedef struct listT {
    listNodeT* head;
    listNodeT* tail;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int dataSize;
} listT;
```

This is the part inside main.

```
if (!strcmp(inputBuffer, "ADD_DECK"))
{
    unsigned int cardsInDeck = 0;
    scanf("%d", &cardsInDeck);
            
    listT *newDeck = newList(sizeof(card));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cardsInDeck; i++)
    {
        card *newCard = readCard();
        addToList(newDeck, newCard, sizeof(card), i);
        free(newCard);
    }
    addToList(deckBucket, newDeck, sizeof(listT), deckBucket->size);    
        
    free(newDeck);
}
```

This is the addToList() function

```
void addToList(listT* list, void* data, unsigned int dataSize,unsigned int index)
{
    
    listNodeT* newNode = malloc(sizeof(listNodeT));
    newNode->data = malloc(dataSize);
    memcpy(newNode->data, data, dataSize);
    newNode->nextPtr = NULL;
    newNode->prevPtr = NULL;
    
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            newNode->nextPtr = list->head;
            list->head->prevPtr = newNode;
            list->head = newNode;
        }
        else if (index == list->size)
        {
            newNode->prevPtr = list->tail;
            list->tail->nextPtr = newNode;
            list->tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            listNodeT* currentNode = list->head;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode->nextPtr;
            }
            newNode->nextPtr = currentNode;
            newNode->prevPtr = currentNode->prevPtr;
            currentNode->prevPtr->nextPtr = newNode;
            currentNode->prevPtr = newNode;
        }
    }
    list->size++;
}
```

Any idea on what might cause this memcpy behaviour?

I tried to add a list to a list of lists. Addition works, but memcpy doesn't copy 2 fields from the list struct, the size and dataSize fields.

Comment: Have you tried step by step to check what's happening ?
Why using `void *` ?

Comment: The accepted first step of debugging before you go to others for help is to take the "real" error, and isolating it into an "error example" which has no practical purpose other than displaying the error ([mcve]). This enables others to reproduce what you are seeing, and avoids having an error in a part of the code you aren't showing. The code you are showing is at the same time too much and too little. Well-debugged, you should be able to showcase the problem in 10-15 lines, max -- and very likely would have found the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: It has a weird behaviour. I tried to manually set the 2 fields after the addition process and it still remains 0. I will further investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like some weird casting was cauzing the problem... Thanks guys for being my rubber ducky lol.